# Use Civil 3D Design Automation to convert landxml file to dwg for displaying in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autocad, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

I want to display the landxml file on forge viewer, but since Model Derivative API doesn't support converting landxml to svf, I decided to use Design Automation to convert landxml file to svf convertable file (dwg).

And because Civil 3D supports importing landxml into dwg files, I want to use this feature and referred to the article below to use Design Automation on Civil 3D.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-civil-3d-public-beta

The code for the command looks like below,

```
[CommandMethod("UsingLandXMLIn")]
    public static void UsingLandXMLIn(string filelocation)
    {
        Database db = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
        using (Transaction trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                string currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(db.OriginalFileName);
                var edf = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
                var sFileName = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "test.xml");
                edf.Command("-landxmlin", sFileName);
                edf.Command(".ZOOM", "E");
                db.SaveAs(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "out.dwg"), DwgVersion.Newest);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(db.OriginalFileName);
                File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "error.txt"), e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace + "\n" + Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "test.xml"));
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }

    }
```

when I execute it, it seems that the landxmlin command fails and returns the eInvalidInput Exception.

So I want to ask is there any other way can display the landxml (with full properties), or how to fix the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.AeccLandXmlOutNoDialog` for export and `.AeccLandXmlInNoDialog` for import. Notice `.` before command name.

```
edf.Command(".AeccLandXmlInNoDialog", sFileName);
```

Comment: Hi, I succeeded download .dwg but the file was losing some entities, https://imgur.com/a/HXmKjjh

Comment: @thanhtrangNguyen can you please send the ifc file to me, mail at forge[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com