# Cannot import landxml file into dwg using Civil 3D Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autocad-plugin

I am tried to import and extract data from a landxml file by importing it into existing dwg file. I have come across this solution in this link:

[Use Civil 3D Design Automation to convert landxml file to dwg for displaying in Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71566085/use-civil-3d-design-automation-to-convert-landxml-file-to-dwg-for-displaying-in)

It works perfectly with my local AcCoreConsole for Civil 3D 2024, but not for Design Automation. Can anybody help me to identify the problem, I can share the log file privately if it is required.

As a side note, I also find this repo in my attempt to solve the problem:

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-civil3d-properties/tree/master/webapp/wwwroot/bundles

I wonder what the relationship of the 2 files from the link above is? Would it be the solution for my problem? Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Can you please share the landxml file that is having the problem, and also please share the workitem log.

you can send the log and model file to aps[dot]help[at]autodesk.com